# IDA - How can I get a list of differing instructions from 2 recorded instruction traces?

Tags: ida, debugging, tracing

I have 2 recorded IDA pro instruction traces, how can I get a list of differing instructions?

I am able to load the diffs as overlays but there are a large amount of instructions recorded that are mostly the same so being able to get a short-list of the different instructions would save a lot of time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is available from the UI, but there are APIs you can use to enumerate trace log records, e.g. see `tracing_api` plugin sample in the SDK.

Comment: Could I please get a link? I've done some googling and read through the help file for IDA but haven't been able to find anything on `tracing_api`. Thanks.

Comment: SDK is available to current customers, check your download email